# JavaScript, 1 image instead of many

Tags: javascript, html

My task is to make pictures falling like snow effect with speed and density given as input. My problem being, I can't make multiple images appear, only one does and it's not continuous.

```js
window.onload = function(){

 var button = document.getElementById("button"),
  myTimer;

 button.onclick = function(){
  //create canvas
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  var canvas = document.getElementById("sky");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  //set canvas fullscreen
  var W = window.innerWidth;
  var H = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.height = H;
  canvas.width = W;
  //generate snowflakes and atts
  var mf = 100; //max flakes
  var flakes = [];
  var velocity = document.getElementById("vel").value;
  var density = document.getElementById("dens").value;

  for(var i = 0; i < mf; i++){
   flakes.push({
    x: Math.random()*W, 
    y: Math.random()*H, 
    r: Math.random()*density + 2, 
    d: Math.random() + velocity
   })
  }
  //draw flakes
  function drawFlakes(){
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
   ctx.fillStyle = "White";
   ctx.beginPath();
   for(var i = 0; i < mf; i++){
    var f = flakes[i];
    // ctx.moveTo(f.x, f.y);
    // ctx.arc(f.x, f.y, f.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    var base_image = new Image();
        base_image.src = 'assume its a cat png source is on my pc';
    base_image.onload = function(){
     ctx.drawImage(base_image, f.x, f.y, f.r + 50, f.r + 50);
    };  
   }
   ctx.fill();
   moveFlakes();
  }
  var angle = 0;
  
  //move flakes
  function moveFlakes(){
   angle += 0.01;
   for(var i = 0; i < mf; i++){
    var f = flakes[i];
    f.y += Math.pow(f.d, 2) + 1;
    f.x += Math.sin(angle)*2;
    
    if(f.y > H){
     flakes[i] = {x: Math.random()*W, y: 0, r: f.r, d: f.d};
    }
    // var base_image = new Image();
      // base_image.src = 'Cat.png';
    // base_image.onload = function(){
    //  ctx.drawImage(base_image, f.x, f.y, f.r + 50, f.r + 50);
    // };
    // I commented this section as I don't know if it's neccessary yet.

   }
  } 
  myTimer = setInterval(drawFlakes, 25);
 };
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="snow.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="picture-fall.js"></script>-->
         </script>
        <style>
            body {
                background: #102a54;
            }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input id="vel" type="text" value="1">
            <input id="dens" type="text" value="7">
            <input id="button" type="button" value="Fall!">
        </form>
        <canvas id="sky"></canvas>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried a different aproach where I draw the images if I don't use the data from flakes objects and it does work although I don't know how to animate them.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var button = document.getElementById("button"),
  myTimer;

 button.onclick = function(){
        clearInterval(myTimer);
        var canvas = document.getElementById("sky");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var W = window.innerWidth;
        var H = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.height = H;
        canvas.width = W;

        var mp = 100, //max pictures
            flakes = [];
        var velocity = document.getElementById("vel").value;
        var density = document.getElementById("dens").value;

        for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++){
   flakes.push({
    x: Math.random()*W, 
    y: Math.random()*H, 
    r: Math.random()*density + 2, 
    d: Math.random() + velocity
   })
  }

        function drawPictures(){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
            ctx.fillStyle = "White";
            ctx.beginPath();
            for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++){
                // var f = flakes[i];
                var base_image = new Image();
                base_image.src = 'snowflake.png';
                base_image.onload = function(){
                    ctx.drawImage(base_image, Math.random()*W, 
            Math.random()*H, 
            Math.random()*density + 50, 
            Math.random()*density + 50)
                };  
            }
            ctx.fill();
            // movePictures();
        }
        var angle = 0; 
        //move flakes
        function movePictures(){
            angle += 0.01;
            for(var i = 0; i < mp; i++){
                var f = flakes[i];
                f.y += Math.pow(f.d, 2) + 1;
                f.x += Math.sin(angle)*2;
                    
                if(f.y > H){
                    flakes[i] = {x: Math.random()*W, y: 0, r: f.r, d: f.d};
                }
            }
        } 
        myTimer = setInterval(drawPictures, 1000);
    };
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="snow.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="picture-fall.js"></script>-->
         </script>
        <style>
            body {
                background: #102a54;
            }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input id="vel" type="text" value="1">
            <input id="dens" type="text" value="7">
            <input id="button" type="button" value="Fall!">
        </form>
        <canvas id="sky"></canvas>

    </body>
</html>
```

Also, why if I change the input for velocity it doesn't actually do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible reason for that could be, you are creating and loading image for each flake object, which you are not required to do. Just create the image object once and draw it on canvas, with flake objects coordinates.

Try below changes :

```
    var base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = 'http://www.clipartkid.com/images/842/image-frozen-elsas-snowflake-png-disney-wiki-bSYAsR-clipart.png';
    //draw flakes
    function drawFlakes(){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
        ctx.fillStyle = "White";
        ctx.beginPath();
        for(var i = 0; i < mf; i++){
            var f = flakes[i];
            // ctx.moveTo(f.x, f.y);
            // ctx.arc(f.x, f.y, f.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);              
            ctx.drawImage(base_image, f.x, f.y, f.r + 50, f.r + 50);    
        }
        ctx.fill();
        moveFlakes();
    }
```

**Replace your image**

Comment: I've spent hours on this, my head hurts, you are a lifesaver! Thank you so much!

Comment: My pleasure.. :)

Comment: @MoloceAdrian welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.